# xslt or php for rendering output

Tags: php, xslt

I'm creating something where users can upload an xml and data get's imported to the database.

Now I'm building some kind of a preview page where users will get to see how their input will look once it's stored.

What would be the fastest (in execution time), using XSL to transform the xml to a html page, or using php to render the output?

My guess is XSL is far more suitable (+ faster) for this (and by using a DTD there's no need for code written validation, right?)

Comment: If you store the xml data via php in the DB, i'd go for php in the view too. But i dislike xsl, so...

Comment: hmm, I can't help but having the feeling that xsl will server me much faster? it just looks so much more native. I also like the DTD validation stuff (because i hate writing validation in php myself lol)

Comment: The validation should probably be XML Schema nowadays, but DTD would work, too. And if XSLT is faster is purely a matter finding out. ;-) You can write horribly inefficient XSLT, just like any other language. Or you might have a horribly inefficient XSLT processor, so it really depends.

Comment: I agree with @Tomalak. Without complete use case this is subjective...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT is slow; often your PHP script will be faster. That does of course depend on your XSLT scripts, but rendering i.e. Docbook via XSLT vs. PHP's own PhD renderer is 24 hours vs. 1 hour for the PHP manual.